# How to draw circles inside each other with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to draw two circles inside each other with ggplot2.

So far my effort is:
**make a fake data and plot it with geom_line(). If I convert this with coord_polar() then I will not be able to see two different circles the one inside each other**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

x1=seq(0,6000000,1000)
y1=rep(1,length(x1))
y2=rep(2,length(x1))

data=as.data.frame(cbind(x1,y1,y2))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```
# plot the data
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x1,y1)) +
 geom_line(aes(x1,y2)) 
 #coord_polar()
```

[image]

I would avoid the geom_circle option and use the coord_polar option if possible.
The reason is that these two circles have some differences in the x-axis, which I would indicate after drawing the circles.

I would like my plot to look like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have with `coord_polar()` is correct, just the plot limits need adjusting to see both the circles, e.g.

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x1,y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x1,y2)) +
  coord_polar() + ylim(c(0,NA))
```

[image: Output plot]

The reason for using `ylim` is that this is the direction getting transformed to the radius by the `coord_polar()`

Answer (score 3):

Why not use two `geom_point()` with different sizes and `pch = 21`?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(x = 0, y = 0)  

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(pch = 21, size = 50) +
  geom_point(pch = 21, size = 40) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]